# Windows Batch Select All files in folder with highest versionnumber

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a windows batch that reads files in a Release folder with multiple Versions for a program.

I have a Release folder like that:

- Program01

  - 1.0.0

    - ivy.xml
  - 1.0.1

    - ivy.xml
- Program02

  - 1.0.0

    - ivy.xml
  - 2.0.0

    - ivy.xml

I need a windows batch that only reads in the ivy.xml for each program with the highest versionnumber. So for the example above it should read:

- Program01/1.0.1/ivy.xml
- Program02/2.0.0/ivy.xml

I only need the code that selects the ivy.xml in the newest folder.

Comment: Does "read" mean show the result on the screen, save in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
@echo off

set RootFolder=Test

pushd "%RootFolder%"

For /d %%a in (*) do call :SetVersion "%%~a"
echo.                 
pause

:SetVersion
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /ad /o-n "%~1"') do (
                                                      if /i exist "%~1\%%b\ivy.xml" echo %~1\%%b\ivy.xml
                                                      goto :EOF
                                                     )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the version number folders always consist of three numerals separated by a dot, the following simple approach should do what you want:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=Release"  & rem // (path to root directory)
set "_SDIR=Program*" & rem // (pattern for first-level sub-directories)
set "_MASK=*.*.*"    & rem // (pattern for second-level sub-sirectories)
set "_FILE=ivy.xml"  & rem // (name of particular file to be found)

rem // Iterate through the immediate sub-directories of the given root directory:
for /D %%J in ("%_ROOT%\%_SDIR%") do (
    rem // Loop through the sub-sub-directories sorted in alphabetic order:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('dir /B /A:D /O:N "%%~J\%_MASK%"') do (
        rem // Ensure there is a specific file but not a sub-directory:
        if exist "%%~J\%%I\%_FILE%" if not exist "%%~J\%%I\%_FILE%\*" (
            rem /* Store currently iterated item; since this value becomes overwritten during
            rem    each iteration, the eventual value constitutes the highest version number: */
            set "LATEST=%%~J\%%I\%_FILE%"
        )
    )
    rem // Return the latest version directory per each sub-directory:
    call echo/%%LATEST%%
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

If version number components may consist of multiple figures (like `2.13.685`), it becomes more complicated because you must implement alphanumeric sorting yourself because standard alphabetic sort would return false results (since `10` comes before `2` then):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=Release"  & rem // (path to root directory)
set "_SDIR=Program*" & rem // (pattern for first-level sub-directories)
set "_MASK=*.*.*"    & rem // (pattern for second-level sub-sirectories)
set "_FILE=ivy.xml"  & rem // (name of particular file to be found)
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path to temporary file)

rem // Iterate through the immediate sub-directories of the given root directory:
for /D %%J in ("%_ROOT%\%_SDIR%") do (
    rem // Open a temporary file for writing:
    > "%_TMPF%" (
        rem // Loop through sub-sub-directories:
        for /D %%I in ("%%~J\%_MASK%") do (
            rem // Ensure there is a specific file but not a sub-directory:
            if exist "%%~I\%_FILE%" if not exist "%%~I\%_FILE%\*" (
                rem // Store currently iterated item:
                set "ITEM=%%~I\%_FILE%"
                rem // Split the version number into sot-separated portions:
                for /F "tokens=1-3* delims=. eol=." %%A in ("%%~nxI") do (
                    rem // Precede these portions with zeros:
                    set "AA=0000%%A" & set "BB=0000%%B" & set "CC=0000%%C" & set "DD=0000%%D"
                    rem /* Write the portions padded with zeros to the left plus a `|`
                    rem    plus the original name of the currently iterated item; the
                    rem    part left to the `|` is just needed for sorting; due to the
                    rem    padding alphabetic sorting equals alphanumeric sorting: */
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    echo(!AA:~-4!.!BB:~-4!.!CC:~-4!.!DD:~-4!^|!ITEM!
                    endlocal
                )
            )
        )
    )
    rem // Read from the temporary file and iterate through alphabetically sorted lines:
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=| eol=|" %%I in ('sort "%_TMPF%"') do (
        rem /* Store the part right to the `|` of the currently iterated item,
        rem    which constitutes its original name; the variable eventually
        rem    contains the highest version number: */
        set "LAST=%%I"
    )
    rem // Return the latest version directory of the current sub-directory:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!LAST!
    endlocal
)
rem // Clean up temporary file:
del "%_TMPF%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: I didn't consider that listing part, if the main version is bigger than 10 there may be show a wrong version on my batch.

Comment: How does it work I substituted "Release\Program" by the real path and didn't get it to work.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the code which I meanwhile fixed…